# Redo is being limited in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often hold Ctrl+z for undo changes then copy something older, and finally hold Ctrl+Y for redo changes and paste the code.

But now when I hold Ctrl+Y it just stop redoing the changes after a certain amount.

Yes, I tried looking into preferences and I found nothing meaningful for the solution.

No, I don't make any changes while redoing, because I know that all the others possible redo will be lost if I do so.